# making appendix for thesis

Tags: appendices, thesis

I need some help with creating an appendix for my thesis. I have about 10 figures which need to be in the appendix. I have a good appendix with the following code:

```
\appendix 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES}

\chapter{XXXX}
```

I have a main `thesis.tex` file where I call this `appendix.tex` file after the last chapter. Problems are:

1. The appendix starts without any notice that it is the appendix except for the chapter number being `A`, but I want to have either a separate page which says "Appendix" prior to the start of the appendix or on top of the first appendix page to explicitly say "Appendix".
2. Now I use the `\chapter{}` command to have the title of the appendix but I think I will have only one chapter in the appendix. Is there some command which can make the title insited of chapter?

Comment: Have you found any answer which you can accept?

Comment: 6 years open and still no satisfying answer. Can you maybe clarify your question a bit more if you are still missing parts in the answers?

Comment: @Geliormth Considering this is the sole post of the OP in the entire SE realm, I think we could just consider Gonzalo's answer as de facto accepted, based on the votes.

Answer (score 243):

The [appendix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package could be used here; the `toc` and `page` package options and the `appendices` environment will do what you need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular Chapter}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Some Appendix}
The contents...
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I change the 'Chapter A: Title' for 'Annex A:...'?

Comment: @F_Jofre_A: `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annex}`.  If you use `toc` or `page`, you'll need to renew `\appendixtocname` or `\appendixpagename` as well.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina is there a way to delete the auto created page where it says "Appendices" in the middle of it?

Comment: @3kstc: That is what the `page` option in `\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}` is doing. Remove it and the page is gone.

Comment: Every time I try to add this on Overleaf v2 it gets timed out, had anyone the same problem?

Comment: @Rodolfo better to ask a separate question for that than try and hope someone finds this.

Comment: Command \@chapapp undefined. \begin{appendices}

Answer (score 91):

A different solution that I use is below.

```
\appendix
\section{\\Title of Appendix A}
% the \\ insures the section title is centered below the phrase: AppendixA

Text of Appendix A is Here

\section{\\Title of Appendix B}
% the \\ insures the section title is centered below the phrase: Appendix B

Text of Appendix B is Here
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of using line breaks in the document body, centering section titles should be done in the preamble, e.g., with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: No need to use \newpage.

Comment: @JohnTortugo In my case I also need to add `\clearpage` or `\newpage` as bibliography and appendices do not start from a new page.

Comment: There is a need for a \newpage

Answer (score 5):

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{phBYU}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
% add abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{acknowledgements}
% add acknowledgement
\end{acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
  \addtolength{\parskip}{10pt}
\chapter{\uppercase {Introduction}} %%add your chapter 1 title here
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\label{chapter1}
\input{chapter1} % filename in curly brackets
% add more chapters
\clearpage
**\appendix
\chapter{Name of Appendix A}
\label{whatever}
\input{appendixA} % filename in curly brackets
\chapter{Name of Appendix B}
\label{whatever}
\input{appendixB} % filename in curly brackets**
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
 \bibliographystyle{phBYU}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{phd}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please learn how to use markup to display code as code. You might also want to describe how your answer improves on the other two here, which have been upvoted often. Yours is likely to be downvoted.

Comment: Thanks Ethan for guidance. I am not sure my answer is better than the previous answers, but they were not working for me. I was frustrated. However, the script which I pasted worked for me, eventually. So I thought to share. In future I will try to follow your advice.

Comment: That's an improvement. Next time you should provide a complete compilable document, including \documentclass , In fact the OP who asked the question should have done that too.

Comment: Please comment in what way your code answers the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If your are trying to do this and you don´t have the expected output...verify where is declarated the `\backmatter`. You have to typped after the last appendix section or exactly above of `\end{document}` statement.