# Adding appendix to Table of Contents using wuthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am trying to add an appendix to the [wuthesis](https://computing.artsci.wustl.edu/latex-style-files) TOC. The appendix and appendices have been defined, but I cannot add them to the TOC. I am also wondering how I can cross-reference my tables into my List of Figures an List of Tables. The corresponding CLS, TEX, and sty are below. Thanks.

```
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{
  \@@nonchapter{odd}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{n}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{\hfil Page}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{\hfil Page}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\reset@font
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \@starttoc{toc}
  }
}
\def\bigtocskip{0.5\baselineskip plus.2\p@}
\def\smalltocskip{0pt}
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth
  \else
    \vskip #2
    {%
      \leftskip #3
      \rightskip \@tocrmarg
      \parfillskip -\rightskip
      \parindent #3
      \@afterindenttrue
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \leavevmode
      \@tempdima #4
      \advance\@tempdima \@@padding
      \advance\leftskip \@tempdima
      \hbox{}\hskip -\leftskip
      #5\nobreak
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu.\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
      \nobreak
      \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hfil\reset@font\rm #6}\par
    }%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{
  \@@nonchapter{next}{LIST OF TABLES}{y}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Table\hfil Page}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Table\hfil Page}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\reset@font
    \@starttoc{lot}
  }
}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{
  \@@nonchapter{next}{LIST OF FIGURES}{y}{0pt}
  {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Figure\hfil Page}\par}
  {%
    \output={
      \let \par \@@par
      \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
        \@specialoutput
      \else
        \@makecol
        \@opcol
        \@startcolumn
        \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
          {%
           \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
      \fi
      \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
        \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
          \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
            \@latex@warning@no@line{Text page \thepage\space
              contains only floats}%
            \@emptycol
          \else
            \global \vsize \@colroom
          \fi
        \else
          \global \vsize \@colroom
        \fi
      \else
        \global \vsize \maxdimen
      \fi
      {\leftskip=0pt \noindent\hbox to\textwidth{Figure\hfil Page}\par}
    }
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\reset@font
    \@starttoc{lof}
  }


\documentclass{wuthesis}

% Put your thesis title below.
%
\title{Sample Thesis in Mathematics Department}

% Put your name here.
% First one is the name you want to put on the cover.
% Second is the one you want to use in abstract.
\author{Steven Xiao}{Xiao, Steven}

% Put your Degree here.
% First is long title of degree (used on cover).
% Second is abbreviation for degree (used in abstract).
% Third is the month the degree was (will be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% Last is the year the degree was (wlll be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% The degree title for all doctoral candidates is ``Doctor of Philosophy.''
\wudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Doctor of Philosophy}{December}{2006}

% Put your advisor's name here.
\majorprof{Cupples Liu}

% List the names of the members of the committee here.
\committee{Cupples Liu, Chair\\Daniel Scott Klazkin\\Jill Goldberg\\Joshua Glatt\\Willam Maas}

% You may put your own abbreviation here.
\input{mydefs}

\begin{document}

\volume

\include{front}
\include{ch01}
\include{ch02}
\include{ch03}
\include{ch04}
\include{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/making-appendix-for-thesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wuthesis.cls` does not provide means for automatic addition of the appendix to the toc. Using the `appendix` package will provide a conflict with `\appendices` command defined within `wuthesis.cls`. However, this can be bypassed using `savesym` package.

The options `toc` and `page` automatically add toc entries for the appendix and a separate page for the appendix start.

```
\documentclass{wuthesis}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{appendices}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}


\begin{appendices}%
\chapter{First of Appendix}
\end{appendices}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Updated example with bibliography in Toc

```
\documentclass{wuthesis}
\usepackage{tocbibind}%
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{appendices}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}

\cite{Lam94}%

\begin{appendices}%
\chapter{First of Appendix}
\end{appendices}%
\bibliography{biblio}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the bibliography as well?

Comment: @JohnD'Attoma: See the updated example.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. Would you happen to know why I get a page number in the top right hand corner of the page and how to get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnD'Attoma: You are requesting many things in one question ;-)