# Issue with hyperref and appendix packages

Tags: errors, hyperref, appendices

I can't use both (`hyperref` and `appendix`) packages together. When I try to compile my code with these two packages,  the following errors arise:

[image: Capture of my log file]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newacronym{ese}{ESE}{Empresa Social del Estado}
\newacronym{huem}{HUEM}{Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
I'm gonna need to use a lot of acronyms like \gls{ese} and \gls{huem}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular Chapter}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Some Appendix}
The contents...
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The code was taken from Prof. Medina's answer:
[making appendix for thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/making-appendix-for-thesis)
Thank you, Professor.

Also, When I compile it successfully, the title of the appendix section is in english, but I need it in spanish: "Apendices" instead "Appendices". How can I modify this?

I'm compiling with the following sequence

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex| makeglossaries -d ./build  %|makeindex -s build/%.ist -o build/%.gls build/%.glo|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|evince %.pdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, load `babel` before `appendix` and `glossaries`, so, at least the latter, knows the language you are in. Also load `fontenc` with `T1` option.

Then add the following lines to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}
\makeatother
```

to get rid of all those errors (`hyperref`'s `\BOOKMARK`s don't like names with accented letters.

Finally, the `appendix` commands to redefine are `\appendixtocname` and `\appendixpagename`:

```
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apéndices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apéndices}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apéndices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apéndices}

\newacronym{ese}{ESE}{Empresa Social del Estado}
\newacronym{huem}{HUEM}{Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular Chapter}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Some Appendix}
The contents...
\end{appendices}

\glsaddall\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]