# Question about appendix of a thesis

Tags: appendices

I'm writing my thesis and i would like to insert, before the biography, an appendix. I've tried using the command \appendix but when i see  the pdf file the programm insert the biography in the appendix.
How can i solve this?

Comment: From a non-technical point of view, I would always expect the appendix to be after the bibliography. If you still want to go ahead and insert the bibliography after the appendix, I'd suggest you take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49647/13272

Comment: @altabg, personally, I prefer to see the appendix before the bibliography, because I regularly flick to the bibliography when reading and it is difficult to find when it isn't the last part.

Comment: @dario, I've guessed at what might be going wrong below. For a more educated reply, we'll need to see your LaTeX code.

Comment: Not arguing on preference. I just haven't come across a lot of articles that would have the bibliography after the appendix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tex file probably contains

```
\bibliography{my-bib-file}
```

before

```
\appendix
%\section*{Appendix (unnecessary heading?)}
\section{Appendix heading}
```

(You need to switch the ordering.)